# Audio duration returns NaN need some modification to run the player

Tags: javascript, html

Whenever I run the script it returns `NaN` for audio duration.

Script

```
var mytrack = document.getElementById('mytrack'); 
var duration1 = document.getElementById('fullDuration');
duration1.innerHTML = parseInt(mytrack.duration);
```

HTML

```
<audio id="mytrack" controls autoplay>
  <source src="kalimba.mp3" type="audio/mp3" />
</audio>
<span id="fullDuration">0:00</span>
```

Comment: There's no `mytrack` variable, and there's no `undefined.duration`. This means, the script executes before the HTML is rendered. *ps: The variable doesn't exist before the HTML is rendered. That's why I sarcastically said, there's no `mytrack` variable.*

Comment: @PraveenKumar `mytrack` would be the `id` `"mytrack"`, which should be global

Comment: @guest271314 Updated my comment, sorry was being sarcastic.

Comment: It is always better to use the event of [`loadedmetadata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata) and then calling them will always work. Using Event Listeners are best in this case.

Comment: @PraveenKumar, That should be the answer...

Comment: Any browser in particular?

Comment: sorry I don't know how to use it.

Comment: @RoobanM Check my answer. `:)`

Comment: @OrangeDog It doesn't works on all browser

Comment: @RoobanM, Try setting `preload` attribute and test...

Comment: @Rayon Added it as an answer. Is it good?

Comment: @PraveenKumar, Yeah... But _"It is always better to use"_ is making your point weak.. `loadedmetadata` is best possible way to get the details about audio...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is always advised to use the event of [`loadedmetadata`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/loadedmetadata) and then calling them will always work. Using Event Listeners are best in this case.

```
var a = document.getElementById('mytrack');
a.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
  var duration1 = document.getElementById('fullDuration');
  duration1.innerHTML = parseInt(a.duration);
}, true);
```

This waits till the media is loaded and then it sets the contents of the `<span>` tag. For best results, please put this code either in the end of the document, before `</body>` tag or use window's load event:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
  var a = document.getElementById('mytrack');
  a.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function() {
    var duration1 = document.getElementById('fullDuration');
    duration1.innerHTML = a.duration;
  }, true);
}, false);
```

As said in comments, there's also another way to do it using `preload` attribute:

> This enumerated attribute is intended to provide a hint to the browser about what the author thinks will lead to the best user experience.

But since you already have`autoplay` attribute, I guess `preload` won't be necessary.

> The `autoplay` attribute has precedence over `preload`. If `autoplay` is specified, the browser would obviously need to start downloading the audio for playback.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `oncanplaythrough` event. `parseInt()` is not necessary.

```js
var mytrack = document.getElementById("mytrack");
var duration1 = document.getElementById("fullDuration");
mytrack.oncanplaythrough = function() {
  duration1.innerHTML = this.duration
}
```

```html
<audio id="mytrack" controls autoplay>
  <source src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/6e/Micronesia_National_Anthem.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
<span id="fullDuration">0:00</span>
```

Comment: Though it is gonna work for sure but should this be used ? What if size of file is say 50 MB ? I am not among the downvoters but IMO, there should a event which will be handy to use...

Comment: @Rayon _"Though it is gonna work for sure but should this be used ? What if size of file is say 50 MB ? I am not among the downvoters but IMO, there should a event which will be handy to use..."_ Not sure what you mean?

Comment: @guest271314, If you go through the docs, `oncanplaythrough` event is being invoked when entire audio file could be played(fully buffered).. Consider the time it will take to buffer..

Comment: @Rayon _" `oncanplaythrough` event is being invoked when entire audio file could be played(fully buffered).. Consider the time it will take to buffer.."_ Yes, there is no guidance from OP at actual Question as to when the `duration` of `<audio>` should be set as `.innerHTML` at `#fullDuration` element. `oncanplaythrough` event handler would set `.innerHTML` of `#fullDuration` when audio file can play in browser, not before audio can play; that is, when duration is displayed, user can click element to play audio

Comment: @guest271314, Audio could be played without waiting for `"oncanplaythrough "` event and that is my whole point.. Though it may buffer on slower networks but just to grab the `duration` property, `loadedmetadata` will do...

Comment: @Rayon Gather your point, though not certain how relevant to actual Question ? ; where OP did not specify a requirement for exact moment during process when `#fullDuration` element `.innerHTML` should be set to `<audio>` element `.duration` property? OP can use one, or each, of several  events, each optional, to set `.innerHTML` of `#fullDuration` element. Approach at post attempts to describe one of the possible several options available.